# Typescript open-api cilent generation and usage of `fetch`

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, openapi

I am trying to generate a typescript client for my rest server. This typescript client is expected to work for both browser and in Node.js environment (server side).

I used

```
openapi-generator-cli generate \ 
-i openapi-pets.yml \
-o output \
--generator-name typescript-fetch \
--additional-properties=typescriptThreePlus=true
```

after this I get this genrated

```
── apis
│   ├── PetsApi.ts
│   └── index.ts
├── index.ts
├── models
│   ├── ModelError.ts
│   ├── Pet.ts
│   └── index.ts
└── runtime.ts
```

When I run

```
ts-node index.ts
```

I get tons of errors like

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Response'.
```

In attempt to fix this I added `tsconfig.json` at the root with this content

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

All errors are gone now I try to use the API (modified index.ts with following content)

```
/* tslint:disable */
/* eslint-disable */
export * from './runtime';
export * from './apis';
export * from './models';

import {
    PetsApi,
} from './apis';

import {
    Configuration,
    ConfigurationParameters,
} from "./runtime";

const configParams: ConfigurationParameters = {
    basePath: 'https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/',
    middleware: [],
};

const apiConfig = new Configuration(configParams);

export const apiClient = {
    petsAPI: new PetsApi(apiConfig),
};

export type ApiClient = typeof apiClient;

apiClient.petsAPI.listPets().then(value => console.log(value));
```

and I try to run it

```
ts-node index.ts
```

and results into

```
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
```

How can I make this project a "Node" project and define the dependency of `fetch`?

Comment: Node.js has no `fetch` since it depends on `window`.  So you may have to check if you are in a node environment or in a browser environment.

Comment: Thank you @kokodoko I am in node environment I assume as I am running `ts-node index.ts` from terminal. How do i add fetch dependency in node environment?

Comment: Check out [isomorphic-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch)

Comment: Thanks @Phil, after doing `npm init` and `npm install isomorphic-fetch` and modifying generated runtime.ts to include `require('isomorphic-fetch');` it works. 

I still think I am missing a piece. It shouldn't be this painful to generate client code for node environment.

Comment: It's not very common to create code that runs exactly the same BOTH in a window client AND on a node server. Mostly, client code is about manipulating the DOM and creating a UI.

Comment: I realized that later, I am going to switch to pure node environment using axios